# Migration from Java backend with simple Javascript frontend to MEAN stack

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, mongodb, mean-stack

I created a client-server web app using Java backend (JBoss RESTEasy, Jackson, MongoDB) and Javascript frontend (just jQuery and some plugins).

Now as I learning Javascript I want to create the same app using MEAN stack.

What should I start with? All necessary tools are installed (node.js, grunt, bower etc). MongoDB with needed data is ready.

Should I start with Mongoose model for my data? Or with Angular part?

Comment: I depends on what you feel more comfortable with. I would say just start :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest building bottom-up from the existing documents in MongoDB to the Mongoose models and doing a quick prototype to replicate a key performance scenario of your existing application. This will help with capacity planning, you'll have real application workloads and a foundation to add Angular on top of later.